# Counterexample in Probability Theory: non trivial property satisfied by indicators but not for all measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

When one has done or studied a few proofs in Probability Theory of results of the type 'The property P is satisfied by all measurable functions realizes that usually it is enough to prove that all indicators function verify the property P, just taking account that all measurable function $X$ can be expressed as $X^++X^-$ with $X^+,X^-$ positive measurable functions, and  all positive measurable functions are limit of sums of indicators function. My question is the following: Could someone give me an example of a property satisfied by all indicators functions, but not for all measurable functions? (I mean a 'non trivial property', not like 'All the indicators have finite range').

Comment: The range is countable. The range is bounded. $f \in L^p$ for all $p$. Furthermore, the following implication holds for simple functions, but not for measurable ones: If $f\in L^1$, then $f\in L^p$ for all $p$.

Comment: Well, I asked for properties not like 'All indicators have finite range', so the first counterexamples are not what I was looking for. But the property about $\cal{L^p}$ does respond my question.  Anyway , I think I have not asked the question properly: I was wondering about the most complex property which holds for indicators but not for all measurable functions.

Comment: It seems highly non trivial to define what you mean by "non trivial" in "non trivial property".

Comment: You are right, the idea is some property which is unexpected to not hold for all measurable functions knowing that it's true for indicators, but this idea doesn't admit a good definition, so I guess formally I can't ask for a better answer that the one of  PhoemueX.

Comment: For something sophisticated, look up "restricted type estimate" along with "operator".

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Thank you, it's seems to be a very interesting topic.