# What is measure theoretic induction?

Tags: measure-theory

I have been searching for "measure theoretic induction" on internet and I couldn't find something formal about it? Can somebody express it formally?

Comment: Where did you read about this term? It is new for me.

Comment: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/21-721_lec.pdf (Look at page 9)

Comment: Maybe it is related to transfinite induction.

Comment: standard machine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018718/counterexample-in-probability-theory-non-trivial-property-satisfied-by-indicato http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069667/standard-machine-in-measure-theory

Comment: Archive link for the now invalid link @Melina posted: https://web.archive.org/web/20211207052453/https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/21-721_lec.pdf